# Click inside cards not working in Google Chrome version 73

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I recently updated Chrome to its latest version yesterday. After that, the click present inside each card is not working. It also showed the error "Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking  event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See "

I tried using other browsers like Firefox in which it works correctly.